How do i solve AOS scroll animation problem?
I have faced one problem several times when i am using scroll animation (aos, tailwind animated) on my react project, the animation won't happen on scroll, it is happening before user comes to the section, Why it is behaving like this?
I have tried using aos, it is not behaving well on scroll.
